# How does Go import resolving dependencies?

Tags: go

In Go, when I import a dependency like:

```
import "github.com/spf13/viper"
```

Which directories will Go look into, and in which order?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Go_Path

Comment: With the out of the box behavior, Go is less than ideal in repeatability, isolation, and consensus. If you follow the setup guide for golang, you’ll find yourself with a single directory where you’re supposed to keep all of your code. Inside of there, you create a /src directory, and a new directory for each project you’re going to work on. When you install a dependency using go get, it will essentially drop the source code from that repository into `$GOPATH/src’.

Comment: @RahmatAligos since 1.6 resolving /vendor is enabled by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookup order:

1. The vendor folder.
2. The standard packages.
3. GOPATH folder.

Run `go help gopath` to learn more on how `Go` search each directory.

Comment: What happens in the case of nested vendor(s) ? :)

Comment: Kudos if you can update the answer now that we have Go modules ;D

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy way to see the search order and exact paths searched n a particular system is to run `go build err`.

This produces output similar to this:

```
can't load package: package err: cannot find package "err" in any of:
    C:\go\src\err (from $GOROOT)
    \\FREENAS\Global Documents\Projects\Go\src\err (from $GOPATH)
```